# Order history Personal Area show image opencart

Tags: opencart

I can not display a picture in my personal account of the order history opencart 3

in file \catalog\controller\account\order.php
find
`'name' => $product['name'],`
and after add
`'image' => $image,` 
front

```
$data['products'][] = array(
insert
                $this->load->model('tool/image');
                $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($product_info['image'], 50, 50);
```

in template \catalog\view\theme\default\template\account\order_info.tpl
added

```
`<td class="text-left"><img src="<?php echo $product['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" title= "<?php echo $product['name'];`
```